# when is code not code?

Tags: support

For [how do I execute a void-returning procedure in pgsql 9.1?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18523/9078), I definitely selected all my sql and clicked on the braces for code format, and I thought I saw it looking plausible.

Yet, when others saw the question, they saw an unformatted mess, and were kind enough to fix it.

What happened?

Comment: Not sure, but you can always preview your post before submitting it. Did the preview look bad as well?

Answer (score 2):

By viewing the edits, then checking the "source" option: https://dba.stackexchange.com/revisions/64cbb858-2af5-42f6-ab85-628f05198cbc/view-source

I see that what happened is your initial indent was (as submitted) at 3 characters on the left hand column.

I can therefore surmise that your original source had 7 spaces or that you inadvertently hit enter/delete at some unfortunate point and removed the space trailing the initial line.

Had you had 7, you pressing ctrl-k would have removed 4 chars from each line, thus making the first 3 chars, which is too short by one for the auto-code-formatter.

It's still there, in all it's glory, for you to go back and review.

Hope this helps, not sure *precisely* what happened.